# How that node.js event loop work and how can it handle multiple requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I was trying to test some asynchronous code in node.js. My understanding is that if there is some asynchronous operation going on, Node.js we will work on the new request. I have written a simple code as below using express and axios.

```
app.get('/async', (req, res) => {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:30000/cpu',
        headers: { 'fibo': '45' }
    })
        .then(ress => {
            console.log(ress)
            res.send('Async success')
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('failed')
            console.log(err)
            res.send('failed')
        })
})
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost:30000/'
    }).then(function (response) {
        res.send('Hello World')
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.send('Something wrong happened')
    })

})
```

Making a request to http://localhost:30000/cpu will take around 15 seconds to complete. So when we make request to /async for this server, it will in turn make a request to 'http://localhost:30000/cpu' which will take some time. Once we get the response back my server will return a message 'Async success'

I made a request to '/async' and immediately made another request to '/'. My expectation is while '/async' still going on, node.js will handle '/' route in the mean time and sends the response back immediately. But I observed that '/' is returning only after '/async' is returning i.e. '/async' route is blocking the entire server.

Can someone explain why '/' is waiting till '/async' is completed and how do I get around with this?

Comment: Your route handler for `/async` is NOT blocking the server.  But, both your routes are trying to contact the same `http://localhost:30000` host so it is apparently not returning a response from `/` until `/cpu` is done.  If you take your second route for `/` and just put `res.send("done")` in it, you should see that complete before the `/cpu` route. In reality, both `axios()` calls are running in parallel and you will see results in the order they complete.

Comment: FYI there are hundreds of answers here on stackoverflow on how the event loop works including answers about parallel Express event handlers.  I'd suggest you do some searching on those prior answers for more info on the nodejs event loop.  You can even search the answers I've written and will find at least a dozen.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don’t believe I missed such a silly point. Thanks again @jfriend00

Comment: What it `http://localhost:30000/cpu`? Sounds like *that* is blocking your server if you serve that route from the same nodejs application

Answer (score 0):

Your route handler for `/async` is NOT blocking the server.

But, both your routes are trying to contact the same `http://localhost:30000` host so it is apparently not returning a response from `/` until `/cpu` is done.

If you take your second route for `/` and replace it with just `res.send("done")`, you should see that complete before the `/cpu` route.

In reality, both `axios()` calls are running in parallel and you will see results in the order that the `axios()` calls complete. So, which request finishes first will have to do with which `axios()` call finishes first.

And, further if `http://localhost:30000` is this same exact server, then the code running those two request handlers also factors into this equation since they would all be competing for the same cpu.